# Backbone pagination scroll issue in Chrome after getNextPage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, backbone.js

New to backbone and backbone.pageableCollection in 'infinite' mode and everything is working fine except when I call to get the next page. After calling to load the next page, instead of maintaining the scroll position and loading the next records underneath "as it's supposed to", Chrome and safari scrolls all of the way to the top of the page, making it very annoying for the users to have to scroll all of the way down again. Here it's the code I use to get the next page

`this.collection.getNextPage({remove: false, silent: true});`

Everything works great in Firefox and Opera, they both maintain the scroll position and load the next records, but Chrome and safari are not working and are the most used browsers for our web app.

I have tried everything from

`var pos = window.pageYOffset;
this.collection.getNextPage({remove: false, silent: true});
 window.scrollTo(0, pos);`

To set a time out and nothing works, it always scrolls up to the top of the page

`setTimeout(function() {window.scrollTo(0, pos);}, 1);`

At this point, I am stuck with a solution in order for Chrome and Safari to keep the scroll position.

Any help will be greatly appreciated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution that works in all browsers maintaining the scroll position. If anyone knows why it'll be great to have an explanation, Thanks!

```
var pos = window.pageYOffset;

this.collection.getNextPage({remove: false, silent: true});

$("html,body").animate({ scrollTop: pos }, "slow");
```